# FFmpeg add logo watermark to live stream

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to execute this commands in FFmpeg and it is working. Now I want to add logo to this live stream. How to do that?

```
find "/video path" -name "*.mp4" | xargs -I $ "/ffmpeg path" -y -re -i $ -vcodec copy -acodec copy -dts_delta_threshold 1000 -ar 44100 -ab 32k -f flv  rtmp://xxx.xxx.xx/live/
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [overlay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay) video filter:

```
find "/video path" -name "*.mp4" | xargs -I $ "/ffmpeg path" -y -re -i $ -i watermark.png -filter_complex overlay -c:a copy -f flv rtmp://xxx.xxx.xx/live/
```

You can't filter video (`-filter_complex` or `-vf`) and stream copy (`-vcodec copy`) the same stream. If you try you'll get an error:

> Streamcopy requested for output stream 0:0, which is fed from a
>   complex filtergraph. Filtering and streamcopy cannot be used together

So remove `-vcodec copy` when filtering the video.

Comment: Thanks for your response but the syntax did not work for me i use the below syntax 


find "/video path" -name "*.mp4" | xargs -I $ "/ffmpeg path" -y -re -i $ -i "Path of the logo.png" -filter_complex overlay -vcodec copy -acodec copy -dts_delta_threshold 1000 -ar 44100 -ab 32k -f flv rtmp://xxx.xxx.xx/live/

i did not get any error but syntax looks incorrect

Comment: @swr You should have gotten the error "Streamcopy requested for output stream 0:0, which is fed from a complex filtergraph. Filtering and streamcopy cannot be used together". You can't use `-vcodec copy` and `-filter_complex` on the same stream. Remove `-vcodec copy` as shown in my answer.